# Issue related to reorder of uploaded documents in media library (Kentico 9)

Tags: kentico

I have uploaded some PDF documents in media library in Kentico 9. By default documents are arranged in alphabetical order in media library.

For displaying, I have used **Media gallery** web part. I want to change order of document **randomly** but I didn't get any option for sorting in media library as well as media gallery. How to change order of document according to requirement? Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try **Media files data source** (with Repeater webpart). This webpart has *ORDER BY expressio*n property you can specify, so you can order your files whatever you want. [image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since the media files are stored in database (Media_File table) you can use **Order by** condition to order your results. The query which would sort randomly all rows would look like:

```
select * from Media_File order by NEWID();
```

So all you need to do is adjust the SQL query with the order by condition. However, the **Media gallery** web part doesn't allow you adjust it so you have 4 main options (although there are more ways):

1) Customize **Media gallery** web part *(~/CMSWebparts/MediaLibrary/MediaGallery.ascx)*

2) Use **Media files data source** web part along with e.g. **Basic repeater** and use **order by NEWID();** in "Order by" property of the webpart

3) Use **SQL data source** web part with **Basic repeater** same way as above

4) Create your own web part